# How to deal with the Hibernate hql multi-join query result in an Object-Oriented Way?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hql

How to deal with the Hibernate hql multi-join query result in an Object-Oriented Way?

As I see it returns a list of Objects. yes, it is tricky and only you who write the query
know what should the query return (what objects).

But are there ways to simplify things, so that it returned specific objects with no need in casting
Object to a specific class according to its position in the query ?

Maybe Spring can simplify things here? It has the similar functionality for JDBC, but I don't see if it can help in a similar way with Hibernate.

Comment: @EugeneP Can you post some example ???

Comment: This is a great question. Maybe this guy might know the answer... http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mb124283/archive/2007/04/java_persistenc.html http://de.linkedin.com/pub/michael-bouschen/0/604/b27

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach is to return only a Root Entity Type, and ensure that the entities that come are (left/right/inner) joined properly, so when you do `entity.getChilds()` the childs are already loaded.

Another approach is to use the `select new CustomClass(a,b,c)` (see docs [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor)). You can create a POJO class called `CustomClass` (it doesn't need to be mapped) and map the query results directly to the class.